# Python pygame list index out of range error

Tags: python

I wanted to program a small game with pygame and first created a character and a resource for it.
The resource should also have different images. I created a dictionary for that.

```py
kristalle = {'grün_kristall' : [pygame.image.load('kristalle/grün1.png'),
                            pygame.image.load('kristalle/grün2.png'),
                            pygame.image.load('kristalle/grün3.png')],
            'blau_kristall' : [pygame.image.load('kristalle/blau1.png'),
                            pygame.image.load('kristalle/blau2.png'),
                            pygame.image.load('kristalle/blau3.png')]}
```

For the resource, I created the `crystal` class.

```py
class kristall:


    def __init__(self, range):
        self.range = range
        self.list = []

    def cords(self):
        for i in range(self.range):
            cords = (random.randrange(-1000,2000), random.randrange(-1000,2000),0)
            self.list.append(cords)
    
    def draw(self, screen):

        for cords in self.list:
            screen.blit(kristalle['blau_kristall'][cords[2]], (cords[0],cords[1]))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(cords[0],cords[1],80,80),10)
```

Since I wanted to have several crystals and didn't want to create a new object of the class crystal every time, I added a list with tuples of randomly created coordinates to the class.
Since the crystal has 3 different images that I want to change later, I extended the tuple to add an index from the dictionary (in def cords this is tuple). In the draw function I then draw the crystal for each tuple in the list. But the error list index out of range occurs there.

```py
screen.blit(kristalle['blau_kristall'][cords[2]], (cords[0],cords[1]))
```

If I just do [desired index] instead of `[cords[2]]` then it works. I don't understand why it doesn't work, as theoretically it should work. I also tried instead of `[cords[2]], [cords[-1]]` to access the last element of the tuple, which corresponds to `[cords[2]]`. But this has not changed anything. I also changed the last number 0 in the tuple, but the error persisted.

Comment: The problem is not reproducible. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I would (1) `print(cords[2])` before the error line to see what the index provided is and (2) check where you are overwriting `cords` because it is being set to an incorrect value

Comment: Check with a print what's inside the cords or self.list objects, basic debugging.